# How to make the input type="number" to not accept number with leading zeros?

Tags: html

This is my current code for the input field. How can I make it display a message saying that the number I've entered should not start with zero? thanks

```
<input type="number" min="10" max="1000" class="form-control" name="payment" 
placeholder="enter payment" style="text-align:center" autofocus required/>
<br/>
```

For instance, typing 020 should not be accepted. Only numbers between 10 to 1000.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="payment" 
 placeholder="enter payment" style="text-align:center" autofocus required 
 pattern="[1-9]\d*" title="A number with no starting zeros"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/spL2par2/

Comment: An explanation of how this works would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

try this using HTML's [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) attribute

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="payment" 
placeholder="enter payment" style="text-align:center" pattern="[1-9]\d*" autofocus required/>
<br/>
```

Comment: typing number 4 says value must be higher or equal to 10.

I want it to say that number should not start with zero when i entered 04. please halp

Comment: That's because of `min="10"` attribute, you said "only numbers between 10 to 1000"

Comment: What I wanted to say is that if I entered 020, it will not be accepted because of the leading zero.

Sorry for bad english.
Thanks

Comment: I've updated my code so it doesn't have minimum or maximum value. If you would like it to have just add `min="min number goes here"` and/or `max="max number goes here"`

Comment: Forgot to change the + into * in regex. Try now.